# how show a message in each cell of the DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

The image in the red part shows I want to do is show the tooltip in the DataGrid when the user put your mouse in each cell, the tooltip is diferent in each

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Data}">
    <DataGrid.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
            <Setter Property="ToolTip">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <TextBlock>
                        <Run Text="{Binding Name, StringFormat='{}{0}: '}" />
                        <Run Text="{Binding TypeName}" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                    </TextBlock>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.CellStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

Assumes a `Name` property and a `TypeName` property on your bound objects.